# print the last 5 articles in the dashboard

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I would like to know how to put a list of the last 5 items in the dashboard using backpack?
I made the table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover m-0 table-actions-bar">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-xs dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></i></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>Titolo Post</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
            <th>Categria</th>
            <th>Azione</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>

            <td>
                <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-medium"></h5>
            </td>

            <td>
                <i class="mdi mdi-map-marker text-primary"></i>
            </td>

            <td>
                <i class="mdi mdi-clock-outline text-success"></i>
            </td>

            <td>
                <i class="mdi mdi-currency-usd text-warning"></i>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="#" class="table-action-btn"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="table-action-btn"><i class="mdi mdi-close"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I made the table inside the jumbotron.blade.php then the function that prints you on screen the last 5 posts  I put it here?  within the dashboard method?

```
$recentPost : Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')>limit(5)->get()
```

any other solution?

Comment: `$recentPost : Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')>limit(5)->get()` is a syntax error... It would be `$recentPost = Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();` (`:` replaced with `=`, `>` replaced with `->`, `;` added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will get you the last 5 articles.

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
```

You need to pass it to the view. Ex:

```
return view('dashboard', ['articles' => $articles]);
```

And loop the articles on the blade file table. Ex:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Author</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($articles as $article)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $article->id }}</th>
        <td>{{ $article->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $article->author }}</td>
        <td>{{ $article->created_at }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yes, I understood that it was like this, at the backpack iteration I made a controller itself for this function